# How to make a Save-file-as dialog box after downloading file

Tags: c#, forms

**Description:**
So I have this following script to download a file from the internet with a progress bar showing what percentage the download is at and custom message boxes. Now I have the files being saved to the users %TEMP% path. And it uses events to prevent people from clicking on the button again and starting a new download.

**Problem:**
I want to give the user a **choice of where to save the file,** but show his temp path as the default location. (Like a Save-file-dialog Box)
I'm still fairly new to coding and don't know where to exactly start.

**What I tried:**
I didn't try any new code, but I did go around google and try to find a solution. Here are some websites that I found that might be useful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-save-files-using-the-savefiledialog-component

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/savefiledialog-in-C-Sharp/

They explain it really well. But I don't know how to incorporate it into this script.
And I dont want to write a brand new script. Any Help would be Appreciated!

```
private bool _isBusy = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  => DownloadFile("someurl1", "somefilename1.exe");

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  => DownloadFile("someurl2", "somefilename2.exe");

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  => DownloadFile("someurl3", "somefilename3.exe");

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  => DownloadFile("someurl4", "somefilename4.exe");

private void DownloadFile(string url, string fileName)
{

   if(_isBusy) return;

   _isBusy = true;

   var output = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);
   MessageBox.Show($"{fileName} will start downloading from {url}");

   using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {

      client.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, args) =>
                                      {
                                         MessageBox.Show($"{fileName} Complete!");
                                         Process.Start(output);
                                         _isBusy = false;
                                      };

  client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) => progressBar1.Value = args.ProgressPercentage;
  client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), output);
   }
}
```

Comment: Add event handler for when download is complete like this client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback); Then handle this event and open a dialog there. You can use a custom form with a text field or just use a save file dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like?

```
    private SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

    private void DownloadFile(string url, string fileName)
    {
        if (_isBusy) return;

        save.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        save.FileName = fileName;
        if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _isBusy = true;

            var output = save.FileName;
            MessageBox.Show($"{fileName} will start downloading from {url}");

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {

                client.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"{fileName} Complete!");
                    Process.Start(output);
                    _isBusy = false;
                };

                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) => progressBar1.Value = args.ProgressPercentage;
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), output);
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Huge Thanks! Exactly what I needed! Wish there were more people like you! 
But just one more question. How do I make it automatically select a default location?(Like the users Temp Folder)

Comment: Nevermind! Had to replace >Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);with >System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();